# How can I create a bold/"cursor" border around a table cell?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I need a cursor that I can move between two cells in a table. Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KNc5u/

If you click on the table, the cursor will cycle between selecting the whole cell, selecting the bottom of the cell and the top.

As you can see, the table "jumps" while the cursor moves because the border width changes. This is ugly. How can I prevent this?

Constraints:

- Cursor must be 2 pixel wide (not 1 and not 3)
- Pure CSS preferred
- No additional HTML elements, please (I could do this easily by wrapping each cell with a `div` with a 1 pixel white border that I turn black but I'm looking for a solution that doesn't add junk to the DOM)
- CSS3 is OK
- I can live with IE10+ :-)

Comment: Is that `padding: 0px 1px;` intentional? It's contributing to the table jumping.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add the padding to the CSS selection rules.

Comment: Better explanation: The padding should be the same in all cases. I just want to avoid to glue letters to the sides of the cells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said you're ok with css3 you can fiddle with box-shadow: http://jsfiddle.net/KNc5u/10/

This example works only with modern browsers and does not using any [vendor prefixes](http://peter.sh/experiments/vendor-prefixed-css-property-overview/) like `-moz` or `-webkit`. If you need support other browsers you can easily add these prefixes to the existing [box-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/CSS/box-shadow) properties.

Feel free to change the color keywords to your needs…

```
td {
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid blue;
    padding:1px 2px
}

.selected {
    display:block;
    border:none;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 -2px 0 #000;
}

.selBottom {
    display:block;
    border:0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 black inset, 0 -2px red inset, 0 0 black inset, 0 0 black inset;
}

.selTop {
    display:block;
    border:0;
    box-shadow: 0 2px green inset, 0 0 black inset, 0 0 black inset, 0 0 black inset;
}
```

### Update

Here is a updated version (imho to hacky): http://jsfiddle.net/KNc5u/13/

However it should fixe your issues for the provided markup. Note that there is a hint: This example will only work in a proper way with similar colors for `td` and your `selected`, `selBottom` and `selTop` classes.

### Update 2

Now with left and right support: http://jsfiddle.net/KNc5u/15/

Comment: This looks very promising. Is it possible to let the box-shadow overwrite/overlap with the blue border? When a cell/border is selected, there should be no blue border visible.

Comment: Maybe... give me some time to figure that out.

Comment: I also ran into problems when the styles are applied to the top/left cell. See http://jsfiddle.net/KNc5u/12/

Comment: Do you also see that "B" is below "A" instead of right of it?

Comment: Sure... i had the same issues but you don't asked for multiple items or i did not understand you correctly so i thought it was ok. I'll take a look...

Comment: In the final app, there will always be only a single style applied but for the demo, I applied them to one table, so it was easier to see how they shifted the layout.

Comment: I created a new version which cycles through all five styles and shows them in static layouts for easier bug fixing: http://jsfiddle.net/KNc5u/14/

Comment: There are now some more css classes in your example. `selLeft` and `selRight`. Do you have some more? ;) See update #2

Comment: Thanks. Why `float`, `display: block` and a fixed `width`? Also why the complex `box-shadow` for left/right?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `outline` instead of a `border` and remove the padding.

http://jsfiddle.net/KNc5u/3/

Alternatively, change the cell background color to highlight it instead of using an outline.

Edit: Erp so that won't do top/bottom only. Turns out that's very tricky without being messy. I've got a nice version here using the background color with a working cursor (click on any cell) http://jsfiddle.net/KNc5u/7/

If the table cells were fixed sizes, you could use background images to give different types of highlight cursor too.

Comment: `outline-top` and `outline-bottom` don't exist.

Comment: @PhonicUK Um, no. How will you achieve only having an outline on the top/bottom?

Comment: Bleh also true. Without getting into anything silly, I suspect OP will have to make do with either all 4 sides, or using the background color instead. Changing the border does change the dimensions and compensating via changing padding/margin doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the movement of the table by adding `padding` to the `td`

```
td { border: 1px solid blue; padding:4px}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KNc5u/6/)**